# How does TimeMachine store Calibre's metadata and backup files?

Tags: time-machine, backup, ebook

This thread is related to the thread [To recover Calibre library from backup?](https://superuser.com/q/947597/2005) which is discussed also with Calibre's active community as [How to recover Calibre from Backup?](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=3142368#post3142368) where theducs says:

```
Restore the Entire Library folder (and ONLY from a single backup). The DB records and title folder (paths) are 1<>1 Pairs. which is why you never mix.

If you need books from a second backup:
1)open as a separate Library and use the Copy to Library context Menu tool
2)Use Add Books.

The first does a great job of maintaining your metadata, which might not have been inserted into the book
```

BetterRed says that I need to *[may need] to recover your configuration data*. 
I run commands in the backup folder getting no outputs:

```
find ./ -iname "Calibre"
find ./ -iregex "Calibre"
```

How can you find Calibre's OSX configuration data of TimeMachine?

Answer (score 1):

To manually dig through the paths, start at
`/Volumes/[TM drive]/Backups.backupdb/[drive name]/Latest`.
'Latest' is an alias - I'm not sure how that will resolve on nix.

The following all depends on the alias resolving correctly, as the actual locations are not 'fixed' but each may be in a different 'dated' folder on the TM drive itself.

Assuming that resolves correctly, then the Calibre plist is at [relative refs to your current folder]
`~/Library/Preferences/net.kovidgoyal.calibre.plist`.

Calibre Library itself is straight in your user folder `~/Calibre` Library.

Prefs are in `~/Library/Preferences/calibre`.